# How blur (focus lost) the image after insertion with execCommand in IE10?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-10, contenteditable

I have a content editable `DIV` such as:

```
<div contenteditable='true' id='myRichTextBox'></div>
```

In addition, I have a button that inserts an image into the mentioned `DIV`. Once the image inserted it has focused with resizable handlers.
How I can lose it's focus and bring back the focus to the content editable `DIV` ?

```
<button type='button' onclick='insertImage()'>Insert an image</button>
```

Javascript code:

```
function insertImage()
{
document.execCommand('insertImage',false,'myImage.png');
}
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work round this in several ways, but a simple one would be to use `document.execCommand("InsertHTML")` in most browsers, falling back to `pasteHTML()` in IE. However, this will not work in IE 11 because it [does not support `document.selection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#legacyAPIs) or the [`InsertHTML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) command.

```
function insertImageWithInsertHtml(imgSrc) {
    var imgHtml = "<img src='" + imgSrc + "'>";
    var sel;
    if (document.queryCommandSupported("InsertHTML")) {
        document.execCommand("InsertHTML", false, imgHtml);
    } else if ( (sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
        var range = sel.createRange();
        range.pasteHTML(imgHtml);
        range.collapse(false);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

Another way which would work in all browsers except IE <= 8 (for which you can use the same fallback as above) would be to insert the image manually using the `insertNode()` method of a Range obtained from the selection. This is the most future-proof and standards-compliant method so is what I'd recommend:

```
function insertImageWithInsertNode(imgSrc) {
    var sel;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            range.deleteContents();
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = imgSrc;
            range.insertNode(img);

            // Place the caret immediately after the image
            range.setStartAfter(img);
            range.collapse(true);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    } else if ( (sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
        var range = sel.createRange();
        range.pasteHTML("<img src='" + imgSrc + "'>");
        range.collapse(false);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

Finally, here's a live demo showing all three techniques:

http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/9ScLA/3/

Answer (score 0):

I used the following solution and worked!

```
function insertImage(imgSrc)
{
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var tr;
    if (ua.indexOf("msie") > 0)
        tr = document.selection.createRange();
    document.execCommand("insertImage", false, imgSrc);
    if(ua.indexOf("firefox") > 0)
        document.execCommand("enableObjectResizing", false, false);
    if (ua.indexOf("msie") > 0)
    {
        tr.collapse(false);
        tr.select();
    }
    this.textbox.focus();
}
```