# How to disable IE image resizing in an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, iframe

How would one disable IE's image re-sizing ability when an image is placed into an iFrame with designMode on?

For example in firefox you can use 
document.execCommand("enableObjectResizing", false, false);

Is there anything like this for IE?

And yes the domains are the same for the parent and the iFrame.

Comment: I have only tried the execCommand as thats the only way I've found so far, and it did not work.

Comment: it's not clear if you tried that already or not

Comment: Edited my comment, I have tried it and it didnt work

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608992/how-blur-focus-lost-the-image-after-insertion-with-execcommand-in-ie10?